# Laravel routing error: GET method is not supported for this route

Tags: laravel, laravel-routing

Can anyone please help me find the exact error in the route?

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
> Route::get('/leave'[App\Http\Controllers\LeaveController::class,'leave']);

```
Route::post('/save',[App\Http\Controllers\LeaveController::class,'saveRecord'])
    ->name('save');

<form action="{{ route('save') }}" method="post">
```

**Controller**

```
public function saveRecord(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'fromdate' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'todate' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'leave_reason' => 'required|string|max:255',
    ]);

    DB::beginTransaction();
    try {
        $Leaves = new Leaves;
        $Leaves->rec_id = $request->rec_id;
        $Leaves->fromdate = $request->fromdate;
        $Leaves->todate = $request->todate;
        $Leaves->leave_reason = $request->todate;
        $Leaves->save();

        DB::commit();

        redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Add leaves successfully.');
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        DB::rollback();

        return redirect()->back()->with('error', 'Add leaves fail');
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is pretty straightforward; you use a get method on a route only defined as a post. You need to change your form to a post method instead of a get, where you are calling the `/save` route.

Answer (score 0):

You defined the request method as "POST" below, which means it only accepts post requests. If you try to go that route from the browser, it gonna end up with that error you mentioned. If you change the post to get it gonna work.

If you making a request to that route from forms or ajax request, just change request method to "POST"

> Route::**post**('/save',[App\Http\Controllers\LeaveController::class,'saveRecord'])->name('save');